# How to set the newly added material to an object as "active" (or selected) material

Tags: python, materials

I add a new material created by this little example :

```
ob = bpy.context.active_object
mat = bpy.data.materials.new(name="Example Material")
ob.data.materials.append(mat)
```

I noticed that the material is added but not active, as in the normal practice of adding blender materials bpy.ops.object.material_slot_add ()
I was wondering how to do this simple step, I tried with `ob.active_material = mat`, but is wrong:

Edit:

This is what I get, it creates confusion and does not set the active slot correctly:

[image]

I would like to get this:

Note that the newly created slot is selected by default (which is what I would like to get)
[image]

Comment: @batFINGER Ty bat, i edited the question , because ob.active_material = mat create many problems

Comment: Sorry my mistake, set the active material index, to newly added slots index.

Comment: @batFINGER Is there an answer I can refer to on this site? (like an example)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To select the last appended material (which corresponds to a material slot in the UI), you can set active material index:

```
import bpy

ob = bpy.context.active_object
mat = bpy.data.materials.new(name="Example Material")
ob.data.materials.append(mat)

# As appended the new material slot index is len - 1
ob.active_material_index = len(ob.material_slots) - 1
```

Comment: Thanks lemon , this is exactly what I wanted